# find and extract values from a table that match a list in R

Tags: r, database, match, extract

I have two tables:

one (table1) containing the ring numbers of caught birds plus all the information associated with that ringing (morphological characteristics, dates, locations etc). The other (table2) has all the ring number from a different campaign, which i already searched and trimmed down for the duplicates between the two.

Because there are allot of rings (>600) it would be time consuming to go one by one from one list to the other and copy paste the entire row of information to a new table.

I want to be able to extract all the rows corresponding from Ring column in table1 corresponding to the values for rings in table2, and obtain a new table with only the extracted values.

I tried to code for one of the rings but it didnt work `newtbl<-as.data.frame(table1[table1$ring==L45523,]`just to see if it would select by ring number directly on table1.

There should be a way of pulling the list of ring numbers from table2 and select only those in table1.

[table1 looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rmG5k.png)

Hope this is possible. Thank you in advance!

Comment: It would be extremely useful if you could make your post reproducible: please see here for instructions http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: more specifically, you could post (part of) your data, e.g. posting the output of `dput(head(table1, 10))` and `dput(head(table2, 10))`, preferably adjusting the number of rows and the selected columns to something minimal though still useful

Comment: apologies I will correct that next time! thank you for the attention and reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a classic relational join scenario. See the notes on relational data in R4DS [here](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/relational-data.html).

If you want the columns in table2 to also be pulled through in to your results then use:

`library(dplyr)
results <- table1 %>% inner_join(table2, by = "Ring.No.")`

If you *just* want those records from `table1` that match a ring number in `table2` you can try:

`library(dplyr)
results <- table1 %>% semi_join(table2, by = "Ring.No.")`

Note that if ring number is called something else in `table2` then you can use the more complete `by = ...` syntax of:

`library(dplyr)
results <- table1 %>% semi_join(table2, by = c("Ring.No." = ["the name of ring number in table2"])`

Comment: thank you very much this worked!  I did want both information from the two tables so the first solution worked great! : )

Answer (score 0):

You can try using package `dplyr` :
 `table1 %>% filter(Ring.No. %in% unique(table2$Ring.No.))`

I am not sure of the structure of your table2 so adapt the code depending on wether it's a list, a data.frame or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Why not do merge on the two tables based on RING, since that seems to be a common column name between the two tables and then filter based on the RING name. Other wise post an excerpt of your two table codes.

```
newtable = merge(table1,table2 , by.x="table1.RING" , by.y="table2.RING",all=TRUE)
subset( newtable, RING ==YYYY)
```

Adpat the code to suit your desiered results.

Comment: Thank you, this solution also worked, gave me the two tables merged by those items, thanks.